# I am trying to copy files to a read-only folder without overwriting

Tags: batch, read-only

I've read the Q&As from

[Copy from one location to another using batch script based on modified date and also newly added files in source](https://superuser.com/questions/1014622/copy-from-one-location-to-another-using-batch-script-based-on-modified-date-and)

and

[Batch File Copy and Move without overwriting](https://superuser.com/questions/724184/batch-file-copy-and-move-without-overwriting)

But I'm having trouble finding what I am looking for.

I would like to write a simple script (.BAT) file to copy only (not move) files from a local C:\ drive to a secured network folder.  Since the files on the local drive are occasionally being modified, I'd like to keep both old and new versions of the original files.  Is there a way to copy all prior versions of a file and automate adding an identifier (e.g., _01, _02 and so on) in the destination folder to newly modified files found in the source folder?  We are also setting up a windows event to run this script every 4 hours so we capture everything we need in case of a PC crash.

Any help is much appreciated as I am a novice.

Comment: You cannot write to *read-only* folder, if that's what you're trying to do. Elsewhere, it is certainly possible to copy files and create a new renamed copy if a filename already exists.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a timestamp as identifier? On my German windows

```
  echo %date
```

returns 25.11.2016.

Using

```
  set ARCHIVNAME=%DATE:~6,4%-%DATE:~3,2%-%DATE:~0,2%
```

in a batch file will make ARCHIVENAME look like this:

```
 2016-11-2016
```

The first number represents the index to take, the second the length of the substring e.g. 6,4 means "start at character six (after "25.11.") and take four characters (2016).

Now you can use the variable ARCHIVENAME in your copy command:

```
copy thefile.org otherFolder\%ARCHIVENAME%_thefile.org
```

This will lead to the file name "2016-11-25_thefile.org". In case days are not unique enough, you can do the same thing with %TIME%.

And just for consideration a slightly different approach:

Create a local subversion repository on the network share by [using TortoiseSVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository.html#tsvn-repository-create-tortoisesvn) and then use the svn command line to check in new versions of the modified files.

Answer (score 0):

SyncBack will allow you to backup files to a destination while keeping previous copies

http://www.2brightsparks.com/syncback/syncback-hub.html